# Is there a difference between the purpose of logic and metamathematics?

Tags: logic

Considering a definition by Heidegger stating that logic is the study of the properties of discourses and considering that metamathematics is defined as the study of the foundation of mathematics from a mathematical standpoint, how do logic and metamathematics differ in purpose?

Could one argue that metamathematics is nothing more than operating philosophical logic on mathematical productions? Could one go as far as saying that the purpose of metamathematics is covered by the purpose of such a logic? Or, is there a substance in metamathematics that is not covered by logic as defined in philosophy?

Comment: Yes; formal logic is dedicated to the analysis of arguments in general, while metamathematics is the application of the tools of mathematical logic to the structure and properties of mathematical theories.

Comment: You are alluding to "philosophical logic": today we have many efforts to formalize e.g. the proof of God's existence, that has nothing to do with metamathematics.

Comment: Formal logic relies on rules of acceptance deciding what is considered acceptable (i.e., legitimate) to "reason on" (and how) and it is definitively part of metamathematics. Yet, it does not separate the purpose (should I say intention?) of metamathematics from philosophical logic in itself. And, I fail to see how the fact that philosophical logic covers more than metamathematics answers the question...

Comment: Maybe some details may help... See [Metamathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamathematics): "Metamathematics is the study of mathematics itself using mathematical methods. This study produces metatheories, which are mathematical theories about other mathematical theories. An important feature of metam. is its emphasis on differentiating between reasoning from inside a system and from outside a system. An informal illustration of this is categorizing the proposition "2+2=4" as belonging to mathematics while categorizing the proposition "'2+2=4' is valid" as belonging to metam."

Comment: A different example: [Prior Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_Analytics) is a treatise on formal logic, but it is not metamathematics.